# Proc logistic to get asymmetric binary model results

Tags: model, binary, sas, logistic-regression, asymmetric

I am doing predictive analytics in SAS using proc logistic to predict a binary outcome to guide decision making.  One measure of accuracy is the misclassification rate, but in my case the desired model is asymmetric in the sense that a false negative is a significantly worse event than a false positive.  Any suggestions on how I can tweak Proc Logistic to try to minimize the rate of false negatives rather than just the total rate of  misclassifications?  Is there some other tool I could be using?

Comment: Have you tried including Bayesian Priors?

Comment: I have not.  It sounds interesting in theory, but how would I implement it in practice?

Comment: I think there's an example in the documentation.